# Does meteor application need a flux-like architecture?

Tags: javascript, meteor, flux

The core of Flux is unidirectional data flow:

- View emit an Action to Dispatcher
- Dispatcher broadcast the Action to Store
- Store make data modification and notice View data changed
- View catch the change notification and make proper render.

But implementation of Meteor platform has similar architecture, as I think.

- View subscribe to Collections
- View call a Meteor method to update data
- In Meteor method, we do the data modification to change Collections
- View re-render the page automatically.

So, do we really need Flux in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think youre making the right comparison here. flux occurs mostly in the browser while meteor subscriptions/publications deal with caching/security and meteor methods deal with server calls.

the purpose of flux is to give your meteor application some sort of architecture, or organization.

from https://atmospherejs.com/meteorflux/meteorflux,

> Flux is a new architecture created by Facebook for their reactive apps. Although they released to the public only 2 years ago, they have been using it for some more time. It has a new set of principles to make it simpler and easier to reason about than MVC:
>
> - It decouples data/logic and views using an event bus: the Dispatcher.
> - The data/logic is organized by common domains: the Stores.
> - Views are not allowed to change the app state, only to dispatch Actions.
> - It makes the data flow simpler (one-way only) and forbids cascading events.
>
> **Do I need React?**
>
> No, you don't. React is just a frontend framework and Flux is an architecture. You can use it if you like, but the Flux principles can be applied even if you use Blaze, Angular, ViewModel, Blaze Components, Flow Components or whatever comes out next month.
>
> **Is Flux the best architecture for everything?**
>
> I don't think so. But it can be useful for sure. I find Flux apps easy to understand and reason about. A lot of Meteor apps lack architecture. Logic and state are spread among the different parts of the app and there is no way to know where is what. Debugging, scaling and testing becomes difficult.
>
> When you choose an architecture you spend less time thinking "where do I put this" and more time just coding because it is clear where things belong. In the long run, it helps you make your app easier to understand, easier to test and easier to scale.
>
> There are many different implementations of Flux, just like there are many different implementations of MVC. This is a good sign, and once you get the concept you can adapt Flux to your particular needs.